# Need Help Updating Bot to Discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to update this code to work with Discord.js v12. I am encountering an error and I'm kinda stumped on how I could fix this error. I have already updated some of the code to work with Discord.js v12.

> TypeError: client.channels.fetch(...).send is not a function

> at Client. (/home/runner/Log/index.js:44:40)
> at Client.emit (events.js:314:20)
> at Client.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
> at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/runner/Log/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
> at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/runner/Log/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
> at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/runner/Log/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
> at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/runner/Log/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
> at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/runner/Log/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
> at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/runner/Log/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const { prefix, token, logsChannel } = require('./config.json');

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('I am alive!');
});

// Messages log
client.on('message', message => {
    // Function
    function isEmpty(collection) {
        for(var arg in collection) {
            if(collection.hasOwnProperty(arg))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    // Logs
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    let username = message.author.tag;
    let channel = message.channel.name;
    let server = message.channel.guild;
    var serverAvatarURL = message.guild.iconURL;
    var attachment = (message.attachments).array();
    if(isEmpty(attachment)) {
        var img = "";
    } else {
        var img = attachment[0].url;
    }
    let embed_send = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(username, message.author.avatarURL)
        .setColor('23c115')
        .setTitle("Message sent!")
        .setDescription(message.content + " " + img)
        .setImage(img)
        .setFooter("#" + channel)
        .setTimestamp();
    client.channels.fetch(logsChannel).send(embed_send);
});

// Message edit log
client.on("messageUpdate", async(oldMessage, newMessage) => {
    // Function
    function isEmpty(collection) {
        for(var arg in collection) {
            if(collection.hasOwnProperty(arg))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    // Logs
    if (oldMessage.content === newMessage.content) {
        return;
    }

    var attachment = (oldMessage.attachments).array();
    if(isEmpty(attachment)) {
        var img = "";
    } else {
        var img = attachment[0].url;
    }

    let embed_edit = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(oldMessage.author.tag, oldMessage.author.avatarURL)
        .setColor('2615c1')
        .setTitle("Message edited!")
        .addField("Old", oldMessage.content + " " + img, true)
        .addField("New", newMessage.content + " " + img, true)
        .setFooter("#" + oldMessage.channel.name)
        .setTimestamp();
    client.channels.fetch(logsChannel).send(embed_edit);
});

// Message delete log
client.on("messageDelete", async message => {
    // Function
    function isEmpty(collection) {
        for(var arg in collection) {
            if(collection.hasOwnProperty(arg))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    // Logs
    var attachment = (message.attachments).array();
    if(isEmpty(attachment)) {
        var img = "";
    } else {
        var img = attachment[0].url;
    }

    let embed_delete = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.avatarURL)
    .setColor('c11515')
    .setTitle("Message deleted!")
    .setDescription(message.content + " " + img)
    .setImage(img)
    .setFooter("#" + message.channel.name)
    .setTimestamp();    
    client.channels.fetch(logsChannel).send(embed_delete);
});

client.login(token);
```

The Original Code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const { prefix, token, logsChannel } = require('./config.json');

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('I am alive!');
});

// Messages log
client.on('message', message => {
    // Function
    function isEmpty(collection) {
        for(var arg in collection) {
            if(collection.hasOwnProperty(arg))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    // Logs
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    let username = message.author.tag;
    let channel = message.channel.name;
    let server = message.channel.guild;
    var serverAvatarURL = message.guild.iconURL;
    var attachment = (message.attachments).array();
    if(isEmpty(attachment)) {
        var img = "";
    } else {
        var img = attachment[0].url;
    }
    let embed_send = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor(username, message.author.avatarURL)
        .setColor('23c115')
        .setTitle("Message sent!")
        .setDescription(message.content + " " + img)
        .setImage(img)
        .setFooter("#" + channel)
        .setTimestamp();
    client.channels.get(logsChannel).send(embed_send);
});

// Message edit log
client.on("messageUpdate", async(oldMessage, newMessage) => {
    // Function
    function isEmpty(collection) {
        for(var arg in collection) {
            if(collection.hasOwnProperty(arg))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    // Logs
    if (oldMessage.content === newMessage.content) {
        return;
    }

    var attachment = (oldMessage.attachments).array();
    if(isEmpty(attachment)) {
        var img = "";
    } else {
        var img = attachment[0].url;
    }

    let embed_edit = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor(oldMessage.author.tag, oldMessage.author.avatarURL)
        .setColor('2615c1')
        .setTitle("Message edited!")
        .addField("Old", oldMessage.content + " " + img, true)
        .addField("New", newMessage.content + " " + img, true)
        .setFooter("#" + oldMessage.channel.name)
        .setTimestamp();
    client.channels.get(logsChannel).send(embed_edit);
});

// Message delete log
client.on("messageDelete", async message => {
    // Function
    function isEmpty(collection) {
        for(var arg in collection) {
            if(collection.hasOwnProperty(arg))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    // Logs
    var attachment = (message.attachments).array();
    if(isEmpty(attachment)) {
        var img = "";
    } else {
        var img = attachment[0].url;
    }

    let embed_delete = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.avatarURL)
    .setColor('c11515')
    .setTitle("Message deleted!")
    .setDescription(message.content + " " + img)
    .setImage(img)
    .setFooter("#" + message.channel.name)
    .setTimestamp();    
    client.channels.get(logsChannel).send(embed_delete);
});

client.login(token);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As NullDev mentioned, [`.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch) returns a promise so it needs to be resolved first. You can either use `.then()` and `.catch()` methods or `async`/`await`.

With `.then()` `.catch()`:

```js
client.channels
  .fetch(logsChannel)
  .then((ch) => ch.send(embed_send))
  .catch(console.error);
```

The same with `async`/`await`:

```js
try {
  (await client.channels.fetch(logsChannel)).send(embed);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

If you've got a function (like `isEmpty`) that you use in three different handlers, you could move this out and only define once. Although you don't even need this. `message.attachments` returns a collection of attachments in the message. Collections have a `.size` accessor property that returns the number of elements in the collection.

Checking if there is an attachment is as easy as checking its size: `message.attachments.size > 0`.

Collections also have a [`.first()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=first) method that gets the first value in this collection. It means you can get the first attachment's URL like this: `message.attachments.first().url`.

Another error is that `message.author.avatarURL` will not work as [`.avatarURL()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=avatarURL) is a method, so you should call it. You could probably use [`displayAvatarURL()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=displayAvatarURL) instead as it returns the user's default avatar if they don't have any.

You can find below your code with all these changes:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const { prefix, token, logsChannel } = require('./config.json');

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('I am alive!');
});

client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  let username = message.author.tag;
  let channel = message.channel.name;
  let img = message.attachments.size > 0 ? message.attachments.first().url : '';

  let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor(username, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
    .setColor('23c115')
    .setTitle('Message sent!')
    .setDescription(message.content + ' ' + img)
    .setImage(img)
    .setFooter('#' + channel)
    .setTimestamp();

  try {
    let log = await client.channels.fetch(logsChannel);
    log.send(embed);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

client.on('messageUpdate', async (oldMessage, newMessage) => {
  if (oldMessage.content === newMessage.content) return;

  let img =
    oldMessage.attachments.size > 0 ? oldMessage.attachments.first().url : '';

  let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor(oldMessage.author.tag, oldMessage.author.displayAvatarURL())
    .setColor('2615c1')
    .setTitle('Message edited!')
    .addField('Old', oldMessage.content + ' ' + img, true)
    .addField('New', newMessage.content + ' ' + img, true)
    .setFooter('#' + oldMessage.channel.name)
    .setTimestamp();

  try {
    let log = await client.channels.fetch(logsChannel);
    log.send(embed);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

client.on('messageDelete', async (message) => {
  let img = message.attachments.size > 0 ? message.attachments.first().url : '';

  let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
    .setColor('c11515')
    .setTitle('Message deleted!')
    .setDescription(message.content + ' ' + img)
    .setImage(img)
    .setFooter('#' + message.channel.name)
    .setTimestamp();

  try {
    let log = await client.channels.fetch(logsChannel);
    log.send(embed);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

client.login(token);
```

Comment: Ah, I understand now. This solved my issue. Thank you for this, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

[.fetch()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch) returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). 
Thus, you need to wait for the result with `.then()`.

In your code (assuming `logsChannel` is an ID):

```js
client.channels
    .fetch(logsChannel)
    .then(fetchedChannel => fetchedChannel.send(embed_delete));
```

currently, you need to update all of your `.fetch`es

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your answer.